# Convert Object to String when object is array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

i want to convert Object to String when the object is an array 
seen like this

```
    public void convertValue(Object value) {

    if(value.getClass().isArray()){
        Arrays.deepToString(value.toArray());
    }

}
```

How i cast value to make "value.toArray()"?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191507/objects-deeptostringobject-o-method

Answer (score 8):

If you *only* want to handle object arrays (not primitive arrays) you can just cast to `Object[]`, due to array variance:

```
if (value instanceof Object[]) {
    String text = Arrays.deepToString((Object[]) value);
    ...
}
```

For primitive arrays you couldn't call `deepToString` anyway, of course.

Sample code to demonstrate array variance:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object x = new String[] { "Hello", "there" };
        Object[] array = (String[]) x;
        // Prints "class [Ljava.lang.String;"
        System.out.println(array.getClass()); 
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `array` value still refers to a string array - but a `String[]` reference can be assigned to an `Object[]` variable.

Comment: if array is MyObject[] can't cast value to Object[]

Comment: @nir: Yes you can. Did you try it? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3 I'll edit an example into the answer.