# Objects.deepToString(Object o) method

Tags: java, arrays, object, tostring, utility-method

The class `java.util.Objects` contains the `deepEquals(Object a, Object b)` method that can be used to compare objects of any type (including arrays and null references), but doesn't contain a similar `deepToString(Object o)`. This is disappointing. (By the way, the private constructor of this class contains the message *"No java.util.Objects instances for you!"* that explains to some extent why this class is so mean). That being the case, I've tried to implement the method myself:

```
public static String deepToString(Object o) {
    if (o == null || !o.getClass().isArray())
        return Objects.toString(o);
    else
        return Arrays.deepToString((Object[])o);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with one-dimensional arrays of primitive types. Do I have to go through all primitive array types with nested `else if`s and call corresponding `Arrays.toString(...)` methods for them, or there is a simpler alternative?

Comment: If there was a generic way to do that, there wouldn't be specific `Arrays.toString` methods for different primitive array types. Note the method bodies are verbatim copies of each other.

Comment: Or, if you're fine with committing atrocities, [see how to rewrite any primitive array as boxed one with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3775583/1384908)

Answer (score 1):

I came to this solution: wrap a primitive array into `Object[]` and remove the outer brackets from the result returned by the public `Arrays.deepToString(Object[] a)`:

```
public static String deepToString(Object o) {
    if (o == null || !o.getClass().isArray())
        return Objects.toString(o);
    else if (o instanceof Object[])
        return Arrays.deepToString((Object[])o);
    else {
        String s = Arrays.deepToString(new Object[] { o });
        return s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

Not very efficient, because it could create two large strings instead of a single one. But with this trick, I can use the hidden

```
Arrays.deepToString(Object[] a, StringBuilder buf, Set<Object[]> dejaVu)
```

method that contains the primitive arrays parsing logic.

Comment: It could just be `String s = Arrays.deepToString(new Object[] {o}); return s.substring(1, s.length()-1);`?

Comment: @saka1029 Yes, but it would be slower for `null`s, non-arrays, arrays of non-primitive types and multidimensional arrays of primitive types.